# open ssh server files automatically with apple script

Tags: macos, ssh, terminal, applescript, automator

Hello respected persons ,

i am trying to build a apple script which first open terminal login in ssh with details and after login it open a python script which is on ssh server automatically . i wanna do all of these tasks in a single apple script . i already tried to build automatic ssh login and i did . but i am facing problem how can i call a python script in ssh server automatically .

like i have a python file in ssh server /home/exe/ai.py

so i want each time i run that apple script it login in ssh and open ai.py automatically .

i am new in apple script please help :(

i am trying it fro 3 days but no luck please help me :(

Comment: Post your existing script... otherwise it's difficult to tell what you're doing.

Comment: thanks you sir for replying i have build only automatic ssh login script but i want it should be login and open a file of ssh server with current session ! please help sir

Comment: Yes, post your code.

Comment: hello sir i am following this code 

`tell application "Terminal"
 do script "ssh username@server.xxx"
 delay 5
end tell`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use another `do script`:

```
do script ("python /home/exe/ai.py") in currentTab
```

**Code**:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    set currentTab to do script ("ssh username@server.xxx;")
    delay 5
    do script ("python /home/exe/ai.py") in currentTab
end tell
```

Note: this doesn't check for errors or handle exceptions, so you'll want to consider implementing something like that in order to deal with it if that's a concern.

Comment: thank you so much sir :) sir its working like charm but one problem its asking again and again password in terminal how i do auto password so i don't have to put password of ssh in terminal

Comment: @exepaul: You'll probably want to use an rsa-key for logging in, that way you won't need to deal with using a password. This is usually the preferred way of authentication if you need a script to login to a remote server. (info: http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html)